# sprintf muted inside function in R

Tags: r, debugging

I am trying access internal variables of code that I'm debugging in R with sprintf.

```
sprintf("sprintf OUTSIDE a function: easy as %.2f",pi)
myFunc <- function() {
  sprintf("sprintf INSIDE a function: easy as %.2f",pi)
  print("print still works")
}
myFunc()
```

This yeilds

```
> sprintf("sprintf OUTSIDE a function: easy as %.2f",pi)
[1] "sprintf OUTSIDE a function: easy as 3.14"
> myFunc <- function() {
+   sprintf("sprintf INSIDE a function: easy as %.2f",pi)
+   print("print still works")
+ }
> myFunc()
[1] "print still works"
```

I've found some better debugging features in RStudio, yet I'm still curious ...

Why does sprintf stop working inside a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `return` if it is not the last line

```
myFunc <- function() {
  return(sprintf("sprintf INSIDE a function: easy as %.2f",pi))
   print("print still works")  
 }
```

Or rearrange the order of statements

```
myFunc <- function() {
  print("print still works")
 sprintf("sprintf INSIDE a function: easy as %.2f",pi)

  }

myFunc()
#[1] "print still works"
#[1] "sprintf INSIDE a function: easy as 3.14"
```

If we need to only `print`, then wrap the `sprintf` with `print`

```
myFunc <- function() {
   print(sprintf("sprintf INSIDE a function: easy as %.2f",pi))
   print("print still works")  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  However, in this reprex I removed my original function's return statement, and now that sprintf is returning, my function is neutered.  How might I get sprintf to print without returning? Or is there a better tool?

Comment: @NickVence I showed two options.  What would be your expected output? If you want to just `print` the `sprintf`, then wrap `print(sprintf(....))`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do.  I'll accept/upvote your answer when you update it.